# can't access larger than 32GB USB drive in Linux (Slackware 14.2)

Tags: linux, usb, exfat, vfat

I have no problem accessing all USB media of up to 32GB in size.
Today I tried using a 64GB stick and while the system recognizes it as a drive it cannot access the single partition.

When I tried manually mounting it, I get this error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Some research led me to install exfat-utils and friends so I tried the fuse-exfat-1.3.0 that's on the slackbuilds site, and when tried installing, the configure command works ok, but the make command gives these errors at the end:

```
/usr/local/lib/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to `_dl_tls_get_addr_soft@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:398: recipe for target 'mount.exfat-fuse' failed
make[1]: *** [mount.exfat-fuse] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/fe/fuse-exfat-1.3.0/fuse'
Makefile:363: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

When I tried to sign up on github on my newest browser (Firefox 108), their sign-up form appears corrupted with a background of an animated space scene.

Isn't there some easy way somehow to install the exfat filesystem without requiring a new computer or new technology to do so?

I mean the only thing I can think of from the top of my head is to reformat the drive but unfortunately that is not an option as it contains data that is needed and only the new camera has access to that data

Comment: What kernel version does your Slackware come with? (Recent kernels have exFAT support internally, unless it was deliberately disabled at compile time.)

Comment: kernel version 4.4.14

Answer (score 1):

Remedy on Ubuntu:
`$ sudo apt install  exfat-fuse   exfat-utils`

There must be a similar thing for slackware.
I have hard to believe there isn't a prebuilt package, but you never know.

Comment: AFAIK Slackware do not use `apt` tool for package management

Comment: Yes, answer amended.

Answer (score 1):

On Slackware you can download package [fuse-exfat](https://slackbuilds.org/slackbuilds/14.2/system/exfat-utils.tar.gz) and install it with:

```
installpkg exfat-utils.tar.gz
```

This is binary package and source is not provided. Check [this page](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/system/exfat-utils/) for information.

This is FUSE tool for exFAT management

The command you may try for mount is:

```
mount.exfat-fuse <usb-device> <mount_point>
```

Comment: ok I tried that, and didn't help. I had to rename the tar.gz to tgz extension and after running installpkg I get the warning `Package has not been created with "makepkg"` it claimed it is installed but when I tried the mount I still get the same error: `mount: unknown filesystem type "exfat"`

Comment: @mike_s, I edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not the USB drive **size** that's the issue, but the **format**. exFAT is a proprietary Microsoft file system. On Linux, install [fuse](https://slackware.pkgs.org/15.0/slackware-x86_64/fuse-2.9.9-x86_64-3.txz.html), or [reformat the drive](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-format-disk) FAT32 (with the limitation no file can be more than 4 GB) or NTSF, or format ext4 if just for use on Linux.

There's are both 32-bit and 64-bit fuse packages (.deb) at [Ubuntu Updates](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/lunar/universe/base/fuse), and [deb2pkg](https://github.com/baguette/crux-ports/blob/master/deb2pkg/Pkgfile) might install it on Slackware, according to [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/best-way-to-install-deb-package-in-slackware-907732/).

Comment: Unfortunately that fuse link you sent me is meant for 64-bit systems. I am using a 32-bit computer. Do you know of a utility for a 32-bit computer system that I can use?

Comment: @mike_s, see the edited answer. BTW, why not just reformat the exFAT drive to a non-proprietary format? If it has data, save it elsewhere, then go to FAT32, which can be used on Linux, Mac, Windows, Android and elsewhere.